# creating a new node in jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jstree

I am creating a node by using crrm as below

`$("#TreeDiv").jstree("create", $("#somenode"), "inside", { "data":"new_node" });`

This function is called through a wizard (i.e I am creating a node in place).
So far I am successful to get a node under `#somenode` in that tree. The problem when the new node is created it appears focused and still editing of the node name is observed.
Screenshot below -
[image]

How can I disable this editing programatically

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Added "skip_rename" parameter at the end in create function to "true" and it worked.
`$("#TreeDiv").jstree("create", $("#somenode"), "inside", { "data":"new_node" }, false, true);`

Answer (score 14):

I know it's old question, but i've used a lot of time searching for an answer to this and kept finding older question with this answer, so maybe this update will help someone. "create" doesnt work anymore for the new version of jstree, use "create_node":

```
var CurrentNode = jQuery("#TreeMenuDiv").jstree("get_selected");
var id = $("#TreeMenuDiv").jstree('create_node', CurrentNode, value, 'last');
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
core:  
{  
    "strings":  
    {  
        new_node: "New node name",  
    }  
}
```